# Spring Boot 2 and OAuth2 client-credentials unsupported grant type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'd like to secure my app using Spring Security's Resource Server and Authorization Server included in my component. 
The desired flow include using only client-credentials grant type and passing client_id together with client_secret as base64 header, what should return token for further requests after hitting `oauth/token` endpoint. I also include grant_type: client-credentials in `POST` request parameters

For now I am receiving error:
`"Full authentication is required to access this resource"`.
The strange thing is despite my configuration Spring still generates random security password what can be seen in console log.

This is my first approach to Spring Security so maybe I've missed something?

Below is my configuration:

**AuthorizationServerConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("some-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
            .secret("somePass")
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(24*3600);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}     
}
```

ResourceServerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}
}
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Security OAuth2 2.0.14.RELEASE.
As in my case, InMemoryTokenStore is used it will work with one instance, what is the best substitute for this if one wanted to create multiple instances of app?

Comment: Do you have corsfilter in your project?

Comment: No, I don't have Corsfilter in my project

Answer (score 0):

When you are storing the users in memory, you are providing the passwords in plain text and then when you are trying to retrieve the encoder from the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` to validate the password it can't find one.

You can try out the following changes so that you can override password encoding by adding `{noop}`

```
@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("some-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
            .secret("{noop}somePass") //change here
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(24*3600);
}
```

And also change your user in WebSecurityConfigurer doing the same for the password.